# return data type of time() library function

Tags: c++, pointers

I found this code  [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm), while I was revising pointers. I read `time()` library function returns a  `time_t` data type. Also I read, ISO C defines `time_t` as an arithmetic type, but does not specify any particular type, range, resolution, or encoding for it. In the given code time function is expected to return an address. Is that correct?

```
 void getSeconds(unsigned long *par) {
   /* get the current number of seconds */
     *par = time( NULL );
      return;
     }
```

Comment: A better version of that function would accept `time_t *par` (actually, that's a rubbish function signature - returning `void` and outputting via a pointer is plain rude).  I assume that the function signature is outside your control...

Comment: A side note: That useless "return;" makes me suspicious of the tutorial, and when looking at it I found the old "[a]n array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array". Do not blindly trust what this tutorial tells you!

Answer (score 3):

Nope, the time function will return a `time_t` value that is then converted to `unsigned long` and stored at the address your unsigned long pointer `par` points to.

You will most likely get a compiler warning about losing precision as `time_t` is nowadays a 64-bit value for most compilers (including MSVC 2017).

Answer (score 1):

No, the `time` function is not expected to return an address. The parameter `par` is a pointer, but you dereference it, and the value returned from `time` is placed in the location that `par` points to.

Comment: did u mean *par =  &time(null); should be correct instead?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: That is possible. But he said that he was “revising pointers”, so my guess is it’s a question about pointers.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann i know it can be implicitly casted to any arithmetic data types.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: The code is correct. What is incorrect is the statement that the function time is expected to return an address.

Answer (score 0):

`std::time_t time( std::time_t* arg )` returns a value of arithmetic type.

`unsigned long *par` defines a pointer to an arithmetic type.

`par` contains the address.

`*par` points to the value.

`*par = time(NULL)` sets the value at address `par` to the current time stamp.

In the given code time function is expected to return a value of arithmetic type.